# How to solve: app installation blocked by play protect problem

Tags: android, google-play-protect

I created an app which i want to publish in galaxy store. It did not publish it in play store. I generated a signed apk with a new key store file. I submitted my apk to  galaxy store dev portal but it was rejected due to the "play protect doesnt recognise" problem. I have read all the answers on the similar questions on stackoverflow but none seemed to be clear. Can anybody suggest something?